# Is plaintext and ciphertext absolutely one-to-one in symmetric encryption algorithms?

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric, ecb

Known conditions:

1. The block size of this algorithm is 16 bytes.
2. If there are multiple encryption modes, then it is limited to ECB mode.
3. Always use only one immutable key.
4. Since only ECB encryption mode is used, things like segment size, IV, and counter will not come in handy.

Due to the fact that symmetric encryption algorithms incorporate [avalanche effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) in order to ensure security.

After simple thinking, some hash algorithms (such as MD5 and SHA1) can be thought of, and now the possibility of collision has been found, that is, different plaintext inputs may result in the same hash digest.

So, after encrypting plaintext (P1) (after many rounds of iteration and encryption within this algorithm), is it possible to make the ciphertext (C1) the same as another completely different plaintext (such as P2) encrypted ciphertext (C2)?

Or, do we need to worry about possible ciphertext collisions in symmetric encryption algorithms?

Comment: Block ciphers are pseudo-random permutations. Permutation means one-to-one and onto and this implies that reverse always exists!

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition of a correct symmetric encryption algorithm includes that applying encryption to any permitted plaintext, then decryption of the result with the same key, always produces the original plaintext. By considering what would happen when we decipher the ciphertext of two plaintexts yielding the same ciphertext (all under the same key), we see they must be equal.

It follows that there can't be ciphertext collisions for distinct plaintext after one application of symmetric encryption when condition 3 in the question holds (and the symmetric encryption algorithm is correct, correctly implemented and executed, and applied to permitted plaintext). The other conditions are not needed.

That extends to encryption iterated some *fixed* number of times if ciphertext is always a permitted plaintext (as is the case in ECB mode for the standard definition of a block cipher, unless there is both padding and an upper limit to plaintext size). It's possible that iterating *a* times the encryption of plaintext A and *b* times the encryption of different plaintext B yields the same ciphertext. This will happen e.g. if *b<a* and B is obtained by iterating *a-b* times the encryption of plaintext A (and this does not happen to yield A).